# Computing a Weighted Average with Liquid Template Filters

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm using Jekyll with its Liquid Templates hosted on Github Pages and I'd like to compute a weighted average, but I don't see a way to deal with order of operations using Liquid math filters.

For example I'd like to compute something like:

```
{{ (page.x | times:.4) | plus:(page.y | times:.6) }} 
--> (x * .4) + (y * .6)
```

But it seems the parenthesis are ignored an I'm effectively getting:

```
{{ page.x | times:.4 | plus:page.y | times:.6 }} 
--> (((x * .4) + y) * .6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquid filters are applied one at a time in the order they appear, using the former value. You cannot change precedence with parenthesis (you can only do this with `if` conditionals).

Here you have to split you operation like this :

```
{% assign a = x | times:.4 %}
{% assign b = y | times:.6 %}
{% assign c = a | plus: b %}
```